# Unable to run mariadb in safe mode

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.1, mysqld-safe, root

When I run following command

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

I get message

`myuser@myvm:~$ 200523 08:24:41 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
200523 08:24:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql`

After that when I type `mysql` then I get following error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

How do I restart mariadb in safe mode to reset root password?

Answer (score 0):

You startt the server with following restrictions

> (Then) ithout a password and with all privileges, and disables account-management statements such as ALTER USER and SET PASSWORD. Because this is insecure, if the server is started with the --skip-grant-tables option, it also disables remote connections by enabling skip_networking.

This comes from [how to reset root passwored](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

The safe mode is only practical, when doing ridumietery things like resetting roor password.

So explain better what you want to do, maybe there is a better or otheer  solution

Comment: I can't login to mariadb due to issue explained here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068155/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-after-new-instal`. In short when you install mariadb it allows you to set password but later you cannot actually login using that password due to some stupid security thing.

Comment: that is really old, install it new, select the "native password" option or create a new user like explained here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-mysql_native_password/ and use this to connect to the database in youir client program.

Answer (score 0):

I logged in as root and now I am able to connect to mariadb under safe mode. That's because according to `https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/` explains that the Unix Socket enables logging in by matching uid of the process running the client with that of the user in the mysql.user table. In other words to access mariadb as root you have to be logged in as root.